# How to create class side method in Pharo 6

Tags: methods, pharo

I know this is a simple question but I have been searching for days and cannot come up with a reasonable answer.

How do you define "class-side" methods in Pharo 6? Something like "static" in other languages

Thank you so much for your help!

EDIT: 
Solved! Thank you!

Comment: There is a Class button right below the list of classes in the Browser. Click on it and it will take you to the class side. Meaning that the selectors on the right pane will now belong in the class. To create a new one, just overwrite anyone or the template. Then Cmd+s to accept. To come back to the instance side, click the Class button again (it's a toggle.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not notice that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Class button right below the list of classes in the Browser. Click on it and it will take you to the class side. Meaning that the selectors on the right pane will now belong in the class. To create a new method, just overwrite anyone or the template. Then <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> to accept (save) it. To come back to the instance side, click the Class button again (it's a toggle.)